# How to write to file without actually creating it on the server

Tags: java, unix, file-io, apache-poi, fileinputstream

The below code works fine on my local machine. But it does not work on the server - maybe because of permissions.
Can I make this work without actually creating a file on the server?

```
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();

XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(Constants.SHEET_NAME);
for (Integer serialNo : reportReq.getSerialNos()) {
    TraitsExceptionReport report = traitsExceptionReport.get(serialNo - 1);
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    createList(report, row);

}

File file = new File(Constants.TMP_FILE_NAME);

String absolutePath = file.getAbsolutePath();
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);

workbook.write(out);
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(absolutePath );

ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
out.close();
try {
    for (int readNum; (readNum = fis.read(buf)) != -1;) {
        bos.write(buf, 0, readNum); 
    }
} catch (IOException ex) {
    throw new IOException("Exception while creating Traits Exception Report");
}
fis.close();
Files.deleteIfExists(Paths.get(absolutePath));    
return(bos.toByteArray());
```

What is the standard way followed when developers will have to write a file on the unix servers.

Comment: You can easily write to memory, e.g. a [memory-mapped file](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_file) or a [ByteArrayOutputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/ByteArrayOutputStream.html), among other options.  Q: How/where do you want to "save" the "file" (the solution doesn't necessarily have to involve a Java "File" object!), if not to disk?

Comment: "bcoz"? Please, no.

Answer (score 1):

POI 5.0.0 added a DeferredSXSSFWorkbook - works a bit like SXSSFWorkbook but doesn't need temp files - it uses a row generating function for each sheet that is executed lazily when you write out the workbook to an output stream.
I just added a simplistic sample to https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/examples/src/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java

There are some tests and you might get the gist of how it works from
https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/src/ooxml/testcases/org/apache/poi/xssf/streaming/TestDeferredSXSSFWorkbook.java

Comment: this has moved to https://github.com/apache/poi/blob/trunk/poi-examples/src/main/java/org/apache/poi/examples/xssf/streaming/DeferredGeneration.java